# Reverse Chronological order of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I have a json object in which id like to order it in reverse chronological order below is an example of the type of data. The actual json object has a lot more data. Thank. you in advance for your help

```
[
{ 
  "name":"John", 
  "birth":"1986-12-14", 
  "city":"New York"
},
{
  "name":"Mike", 
  "birth":"1996-1-24", 
  "city":"Los Angeles"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var people = [
  { 
    "name":"John", 
    "birth":"1986-12-14", 
    "city":"New York"
  },
  {
    "name":"Mike", 
    "birth":"1996-1-24", 
    "city":"Los Angeles"
  }
];


var peopleDescOrder = people.sort((a,b) => new Date(b['birth']) - new Date(a['birth']));
console.log(peopleDescOrder);
```

`new Date()` creates a date object from 'birth' string. Then the two dates are compared to order them.

Comment: Is there a reason you're explicitly calling the `getTime` function? I've always just subtracted the date objects directly.

Comment: Ah, habit. Looks like there is no apparent usefulness in calling getTime(). Updating the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm writing this answer because sorting by dates in Javascript is one of those weird and wonky things you get used to doing the more times you have to do it.

If you *can* modify the data that gets sent from whatever source you are using, I'd recommend making the months/dates lead with a zero, i.e. `1996-1-24` should become `1996-01-24`, and something like `1984-1-3` would become `1984-01-03`. If you do not have control over it, then don't worry about it; if you are responsible for that data as well, this small edit will save you some frustrations.

Let's start with some examples of using the "leading zero" format vs not.

```js
let sept = '2020-09-01';
let oct = '2020-10-01';

// Before you run the snippet: is October 1st before or after September first?
// It's after, therefore, we would expect for date object comparisons that the .getTime() method for an October date object is greater than the .getTime() method for any September date object. 

// Will this match our logic above? will october be greater than september?
console.log(oct > sept);

// let's change our dates to use a non-leading zero format

sept = '2020-9-1';
oct = '2020-10-1';

// Will this still be true?
console.log(oct > sept);
```

If you've ran the snippet, you'll know that we get `true` in our console for the first part, and `false` for the second. Why?

Well, it has to do with how that same 'alphabetizing' algorithm works. I think it makes the most sense to just see the code.

```js
let sept = '2020-9-1';
let oct = '2020-10-1';

for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(sept.length, oct.length); i++) {
  console.log(`Comparing ${sept[i]} with ${oct[i]}`);
  if(sept[i] > oct[i]) {
    console.log(`"sept" is greater than "oct" because ${sept[i]} is greater than ${oct[i]} at position ${i}`);
    break;
  }
}

// let's switch the dates to have leading zeroes so that the date/month parts are always 2 characters long and run mostly the same code as above.

sept = '2020-09-01';
oct = '2020-10-01';

console.log('-----');

for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(sept.length, oct.length); i++) {
  console.log(`Comparing ${sept[i]} with ${oct[i]}`);
  if(sept[i] > oct[i]) {
    console.log(`"sept" is greater than "oct" because ${sept[i]} is greater than ${oct[i]} at position ${i}`);
    break;
  }
  // added a new section
  if(oct[i] > sept[i]) {
    console.log(`"oct" is greater than "sept" because ${oct[i]} is greater than ${sept[i]} at position ${i}`);
    break;
  }
}
```

When you run the above snippet you'll see sort of the internals of how the algorithm to compare strings works. The first bit tells us that september 1st happens before october first, which we know to be wrong. It does this because when it gets to the 5th position in the string the algorithm is comparing 9 to 1. Well, 9 is greater than 1, so it incorrectly tells us that `sept` is greater than `oct`

The second section fixes the dates so that they have leading zeroes for numbers less than 10. In that code I added another check and we see it (correctly) telling us that october is greater than september. Woo!

**Disclaimer** with all these said, there is nothing wrong with Chethan7's answer above; I am only writing this because it's information I wish I would've known when I had to work with date and date strings in JS. I also mention it because of how the `.sort()` function works, this could theoretically create quite a few `Date` objects that will eventually need to be garbage collected and you mention that there is a lot more data than you've given in your example.

That being said, if you would be able to change the date strings, then Chethan7s code could be rewritten as

```js
var people = [
  { 
    "name":"John", 
    "birth":"1986-12-14", 
    "city":"New York"
  },
  {
    "name":"Mike", 
    "birth":"1996-01-24", 
    "city":"Los Angeles"
  }
];


var peopleDescOrder = people.sort((a,b) => b > a ? 1 : -1);
console.log(peopleDescOrder);
```